# How to mock this.method() inside a method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

When `(mock.method()).thenReturn(obj)` does not work. I also tried spying but I don't want to call the actual method, I just want a response to be sent when `this.method()` is hit.

Any tips?

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.19.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Comment: **You don't**, you are supposed to test the public method, the internal calls to helpers must not matter to you. If they are too complex / do too much work then you need to extract them to a different class and mock that class instead

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but you have to use a `spy`. Make a spy on your object and define this behavior:

```
doReturn(obj).when(spy).method()
```

Then you can call your outer method and the inner call to `method()` will immediately return `obj`.